# Test-module import failures after migrating to plone.app.testing - apparently circular imports

Tags: python, testing, plone

I'm facing an issue migrating our Plone site to using plone.app.testing.  I'm getting the message `Test-module import failures` as the first line outputted on the console.

```
C:\sandbox\cms.buildout>bin\test -s soschildrensvillages
Test-module import failures:

Module: soschildrensvillages.contenttypes.tests.test_portlet_concept_news

Traceback (most recent call last):
...
  File "c:\sandbox\cms.buildout\src\soschildrensvillages\soschildrensvillages\contenttypes\content\concept_folder.py", line 7, in <module>
    from plone.app.folder.folder import ATFolder
  File "c:\sandbox\cms.buildout\eggs\plone.app.folder-1.0.5-py2.7.egg\plone\app\folder\folder.py", line 4, in <module>
    from Products.ATContentTypes.interface import IATFolder
  File "c:\sandbox\cms.buildout\eggs\products.atcontenttypes-2.1.13-py2.7.egg\Products\ATContentTypes\__init__.py", line 32, in <module>
    import Products.ATContentTypes.content
  File "c:\sandbox\cms.buildout\eggs\products.atcontenttypes-2.1.13-py2.7.egg\Products\ATContentTypes\content\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    import Products.ATContentTypes.content.folder
  File "c:\sandbox\cms.buildout\eggs\products.atcontenttypes-2.1.13-py2.7.egg\Products\ATContentTypes\content\folder.py", line 19, in <module>
    from plone.app.folder import folder
ImportError: cannot import name folder
```

There are more import errors as it tries to set-up testing layers and run tests.  Only the unit tests (plain TestCase) run without error.

These errors only started appearing after I migrated the last test from `Products.PloneTestCase` and including the following line in our testing.py module solves the issue.

```
from Products.PloneTestCase import PloneTestCase as ptc
```

I'm not sure what level of detail someone will need to help out here but any pointers to what I could try would be most appreciated.

Our testing.py looks like

```
products = ('collective.lineage', 'soschildrensvillages')


class SOSChildrenLayer(PloneWithPackageLayer):

    defaultBases = (PLONE_FIXTURE,)

    def __init__(self):
        super(SOSChildrenLayer, self).__init__(
                zcml_filename='configure.zcml', zcml_package=soschildrensvillages,
                additional_z2_products=products, gs_profile_id='soschildrensvillages:default'
        )

    def setUpZCMLFiles(self):
        super(SOSChildrenLayer, self).setUpZCMLFiles()
        self.loadZCML(name='overrides.zcml', package=soschildrensvillages)

    def tearDownZope(self, app):
        super(SOSChildrenLayer, self).tearDownZope(app)
        for product in products:
            z2.uninstallProduct(app, product)


SOS_CHILDREN_FIXTURE = SOSChildrenLayer()
SOS_CHILDREN_INTEGRATION_TESTING = IntegrationTesting(
        bases=(SOS_CHILDREN_FIXTURE,), 
        name="SOSChildren:Integration"
    )
```

In setup.py we have

```
  install_requires=[
      'setuptools',

      'collective.lineage',

      'plone.app.caching',
      'plone.app.folder',
      'plone.app.iterate',

      'quintagroup.seoptimizer',

      'rdflib',

      'soschildrensvillages.taxonomy',          
      'soschildren.contentexperiments',          

      'Products.AdvancedQuery',
      'Products.ATContentTypes',
      'Products.CMFPlone',
      'Products.CMFPlacefulWorkflow'
      # -*- Extra requirements: -*-
  ],
```

In configure.zcml we have

```
  <includeDependencies package="." />
```

concept_folder.py includes the definition of a Archetypes content type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by ensuring I imported something from Products.ATContentTypes before plone.app.folder in my module where the error was originating.

Before

```python
from plone.app.folder.folder import ATFolder
from plone.app.folder.folder import ATFolderSchema
from Products.ATContentTypes.content.schemata import finalizeATCTSchema
```

After

```python
from Products.ATContentTypes.content.schemata import finalizeATCTSchema
from plone.app.folder.folder import ATFolder
from plone.app.folder.folder import ATFolderSchema
```